# SciChart annotation that is on the axis and above with "normal" paning behavior

Tags: wpf, annotations, scichart

I have a situation in which I have a chart annotation that represents an event that happened. I want to add a marker that consists of several icons in the middle of it (see `1` and `2`):

[image]

I tried the `axismarkerannotation` but it has a weird behavior of snapping its middle point and when it is paning out of range it disappears.
I saw there is the possibility to place an annotation on the `ModifierSurface` but couldn't find an example.

I will fiddle around with this approach but perhaps someone has an solution for this? I want both markers to be visible and not when the potin in between `1` and `2` is out of sight both dissapear...
Is treating both icons as seperate annotations the only viable solution?

Comment: Have you looked at Composite Annotation? https://www.scichart.com/documentation/win/current/webframe.html#The%20CompositeAnnotation%20Type.html It provides the ability to group annotations into one. Also setting `SciChartSurface.ClipOverlayAnnotations = false` means you can draw outside the main viewport and over the axis.